# data transformation and heatmap by clusters

Tags: pandas, dplyr

I would like to transform my data to do a heatmap.
So I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to transform it to this:
[image]

I would then make a heatmap where I group by "Cluster"? Is this feasible?

Comment: please provide a copyable example of your data

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found out out how to do the heatmap.
So, original data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("Ensembl"= paste("ENS", len(1:10),sep=""), "samp1"= rep(1,10), "samp2"= rep(3, 10), "sampC1" = rep(10,10), "sampC2" = rep(0.5,10), "Cluster" = c(rep("hub1",2), rep("hub7", 5), rep("hub108",3)), "scaledGeneLoci" = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.74, 0.82, 0.85, 0.9, 10))
```

I transformed like this:

```
df_melt <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Ensembl", "Cluster", "scaledGeneLoci")
df_trans <- df_melt %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "scaledGeneLoci", values_from = "value")
```